# How do I 'drop' an sqlite DB on an unrooted Android phone?

Tags: android, sqlite

Before I found out about that adb shell doesn't have the permission to do much with /data/data I was using my unrooted Verizon Droid for development of a content provider. How do I get rid of the database I created there? Is my best option writing a small app that drops the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any content in /data/data (or wherever else the permissions specify) can only be accessed by the application that owns those files (unless you specifically made something world writeable).

I'm not sure about the situation you have here. You have a file in /data/data? How was that created? Using an app you wrote? If you uninstall that app (adb uninstall com.package.app), all data in /data/data that belongs to this app will be destroyed as well.